# Show this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

When I was doing a task of analysis, I was stuck on the following question:
Let $f$ be a real negative, decreasing and convex function defined on $[1,+\infty[$ such that $f(1)=0.$ It is clear that $f(x)\leq 0.$ Show that $$f(x) \leq (1-x).$$
Many thanks,
Khadija

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but does $\frac 1 2 (1 - x)$ not serve as a counterexample to this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the function to be concave? Any strictly convex decreasing function will be greater than $(1-x)$ (if we also have some kind of normalizing condition to prevent counterexamples such as @user's)

Comment: @Soke  Thank you for your reply! Is there a real $x \geq 1$ giving the equality $f(x)=1-x$?

Comment: I mean $x>1$ such that $f(x)=1-x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the problem with the question is that it does not give some kind of normalizing condition (thereby allowing counterexamples such as @user's $\frac{1}{2}(1-x)$) and it says convex when I believe it should be concave.

To prevent counterexamples such as @user's, we could give a normalizing condition, in particular that we have $f'(1) = -1$.

Now, clearly the behavior of such functions $f$ depends on its second derivative $f''$.

If $f'' = 0$, then one sees that $f(x) = (1-x)$ since $f' = -1$ constantly.

If $f'' < 0$ (strictly concave), then clearly we will have $f(x) < 1-x$.

Thus the result follows.